# Objective C class inheritance with factory methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, inheritance

I would like to inherit from a framework class that has a factory method. How can I make the factory method return an object of my inherited class type? I found [this useful article](http://qualitycoding.org/factory-method/) which describe a similar situation but in their case you have control over the superclass. How  could I write, say, a subclass of `UIImage` that `imageNamed:` would return an object of my subclass type?

Comment: maybe you can achieve what you want by writing a category on UIImage?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking now about this direction. Only that I need some additional class members (properties) and wanted to avoid the hassle with objc_setAssociatedObject and friends. Also because I do not find it elegant to create a workaround of this type for a completely different problem. However I am afraid more and more that I have no choice.

Comment: take a look at this [NSObject](https://github.com/pixelflut/PixLib-OpenSource/blob/master/PixLib%20OpenSource/NSObject%2BPixLib.m) category. The two methods `setRuntimeProperty:name:` and `runtimeProperty:` help to convinient set and access associated objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would like to inherit from a framework class that has a factory method. How can I make the factory method return an object of my inherited class type?

This is all you *should* have to do:

```
@interface MONImage : UIImage
@end

@implementation MONImage
@end
```

Then:

```
MONImage * image = [MONImage imageNamed:name];
```

---

> How could I write, say, a subclass of UIImage that imageNamed: would return an object of my subclass type?

`+[UIImage imageNamed:]`'s implementation wrote subclassers out of this approach. Consequently, you would need to implement this method yourself.

Here's how one *should* declare a factory method:

```
+ (instancetype)imageNamed:(NSString *)pName;
```

and how one *should* implement it:

```
+ (instancetype)imageNamed:(NSString *)pName
{
  MONImage * image = [[self alloc] initWithThisDesignatedInitializer:pName];
                       ^^^^ NOTE: self, not a concrete class
  ...set up image...
  return image;
}
```

but they did not do it that way -- `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` wrote subclasses out and returns a `UIImage` when you write `MONImage * img = [MONImage imageNamed:pName];`. Sometimes that is done for a good reason. Some methods should have 'final' semantics. This often appears when your method may return multiple types, as in a class cluster. The language does not express 'final' methods -- but such a method should at least be documented.

---

So to come around to this `UIImage` case:

```
@interface MONImage : UIImage

+ (instancetype)imageNamed:(NSString *)pName;

@end

@implementation MONImage

+ (instancetype)imageNamed:(NSString *)pName
{
    UIImage * source = [UIImage imageNamed:pName];
    CGImageRef cgImage = source.CGImage;
    if (cgImage)
        return [[self alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    // try it another way
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Note that `UIImage`s and `CGImage`s are immutable. This should not result result in a deep copy of the image data.

Comment: does this also provide the caching Behavior of `[UIImage imageNamed:]`? If not, maybe you should store a reference to the original image in `MONImage`. But really nice solution.

Comment: @JonathanCichon it would preserve lookup behavior of `+imageNamed:`. it would load the image, then cache it. the exact behavior of the caching implementation is abstracted so my conclusion is that it is not guaranteed to be identical in this regard. I *suppose* it would be the same regarding caching, but I have not proven that. good question.

Answer (score 3):

For your example:

- Subclass `UIImage` to, say, `MyImage`
- Implement the `imageNamed:` method to do anything specific that you need to be done.
- Call that method on that class: `MyImage *newImage = [MyImage imageNamed:imageName];`

Comment: This will not really help, as you can not call `super` in your own implementation of `imageNamed`, as this will end up in returning a instance of type `UIImage`.

Comment: Who says he needs to call super? he can alloc and init an object of his subclass within the method and return that. And, as we all know, the convention is for subclasses to call their superclass's designated initialiser, which returns an object of type `id`. Anyway, this is a contrived example based on what the OP asked for. The details are left to the user, but the principle of a convenience constructor alloc and init'ing an object of it's own class is sound.

Comment: yes, but in this case, the 'magic' apple does in `imageNamed:` is very usefull and i dont think he wants to implement this by himself. But you are right, your answer is not 'wrong' but i think not very usefull in THIS case.

Comment: My particular problem is that I do not want to provide an alternative implementation of imageNamed, it would be just fine for me as it is if it would return a MyImage instance. And UIImage does not have an init... method analog to imageNamed: that considers also image caching so I can't even override it keeping the same functionality - just as Jonathan says.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that solved my problem was to use a category instead of inheritance (credits go to Jonathan Cichon in the comments of my question). I used [Associative References](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-SW5) to declare and store additional data in the category implementation as discussed a lot here in SO. I would like to drive the attention to the [`NSObject` category implementation](https://github.com/pixelflut/PixLib-OpenSource/blob/master/PixLib%20OpenSource/NSObject+PixLib.m) proposed by Jonathan that makes really easy and elegant to add associative references to any object.

Comment: While I'm glad you solved your problem - your question was about overriding convenience constructors, which you then changed to a question about adding storage to a class outside of a class extension.  So there are really two sets of questions and answers going on at the same time.

Comment: I needed to extend the original framework class with additional data and still be able to use its original convenience constructors. When I asked the original question I had no idea how to do this and supposed that it can be achieved with inheritance. You are right from the point of view that I did not specify exactly that I need to add additional data to the class, but wrote "inheritance". On the other hand Jonathan's solution perfectly solves my problem even if not using inheritance.

Comment: NB: I did not change the original question and added the hint of assoc.refs in this answer only as a reference for future readers.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that what you asked for and what you really wanted to know were two separate things.